# how to calculate total balance per state per country using accumulate function in openedge

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have tried the code.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE totalbalance AS DECIMAL     NO-UNDO.

DEFINE FRAME f1

    WITH CENTERED THREE-D SIZE 100 BY 50.
FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK BREAK BY country WITH FRAME f1:

    ACCUMULATE balance(TOTAL BY country).
    IF FIRST-OF(customer.country) THEN
        DISPLAY customer.country.
    DISPLAY customer.state customer.balance.
    IF LAST-OF(customer.country) THEN
    DO:   
         DISPLAY SKIP FILL("-", 25) AT 50 FORMAT "x(25)".
         DISPLAY ACCUM TOTAL customer.balance AT 51.
         DISPLAY SKIP FILL("-", 25) AT 50 FORMAT "x(25)".
    END.
END.
```

It only gives total balance per country but I also want to display total balance per state.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a "break by state" so it will do nothing by state.

Something like this (not very tested):

```
define frame f1
  with
   centered
.

for each customer no-lock break by country by state with frame f1:

    accumulate balance( total by country ).
    accumulate balance( sub-total by state ).

    if first-of( customer.country ) then
        display customer.country.

    if first-of( customer.state ) then
        display customer.state.

    display customer.balance.

    if last-of( customer.country ) then
      do:
        display skip fill( "-", 25 ) at 50 format "x(25)".
        display accum total customer.balance at 51.
        display skip fill( "-", 25 ) at 50 format "x(25)".
      end.

    if last-of( customer.state ) then
      do:
        display skip fill( "-", 25 ) at 80 format "x(25)".
        display accum sub-total customer.balance at 81.
        display skip fill( "-", 25 ) at 80 format "x(25)".
      end.

end.
```

(That probably doesn't actually work... but the multiple BY clauses are the main thing that you are missing.)

Personally I find the ACCUM syntax to be unpleasant and not worth bothering with.  I usually just create and manage simple variables.  I find that sort of coding to be much cleaner.  So unless this is a "gotchya" question on a skills test I strongly suggest that you avoid coding in this manner.  If it is a "gotchya" question move on to a more suitable prospective employer -- you don't want to work for anyone who thinks that this is a good idea.

I would do it more like this:

```
define variable countryBalance as decimal no-undo.
define variable stateBalance   as decimal no-undo.

for each customer no-lock break by country by state with frame f1:

    if first-of( customer.country ) then
      do:
        display customer.country.
        countryBalance = 0.
      end.

    if first-of( customer.state ) then
      do:
        display customer.state.
        statebalance = 0.
      end.

    assign
      countryBalance = countryBalance + customer.balance
      stateBalance   = stateBalance  + customer.balance
    .

    display customer.balance.

    if last-of( customer.country ) then
      do:
        display countryBalance.
      end.

    if last-of( customer.state ) then
      do:
        display stateBalance.
      end.

end.
```

I think that is a whole lot easier to read, understand and maintain.